# Using svn versioning between eclipse and ibm rad 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive, ibm-rad

I use eclipse and ibm rad 8 and since rad 8 is built on eclipse i should be able to version a project using both IDE:s. So I checked in a project from eclipse to xp-dev.com in svn and checked it out with ibm rad 8 which can't build the project. The views are as follows.

[image]

[image]
[image]

When I build from ibm rad this error occurs.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: adventure.Adventure
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: adventure.Adventure
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

There seems to be an issue with my build path that is defined for Java 7. This is my first Java 7 project and my IDe can't find the version 7 though it's installed at the computer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: the big red exclamation mark tells you that something is wrong with your build path, can you do a project --> clean?

Comment: @oers thanks for the comment. I did a project...clean and the exclamation mark is still there. I can provide more details about my problem if you tell me where to look.

Comment: in the problems view there should be more information about the problem. Check your BuildPath and make sure that a correct JVM is selected.

Comment: @oers I've installed java 7 but the Ide can't find it. It highlights the Java 7 JRE red. It can java 6 but this project should be Java 7 and it's my first Java 7 project. I have Java 7 from the command line but RAD can't seem to find it. I might do add external JARs but I think the RAD should be aware of my latest Java installation.

Comment: [See: Adding a new JRE definition](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-add_new_jre.htm)

Comment: @oers You're right, when I go to the execution environment setting display (see updated question) there is no JRE for my Java 7 and I don't see where I can add one. This might be some difference between Eclipse and RAD and if you look at my updated question you can see the status of the problem if you want to help further. Many thanks...

Comment: what happens if you follow the guide I linked? this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not version your `.settings` folder.  This will be different depending on the location and type of your IDE.  This should be added to `svn:ignore` together with the `.classpath` and `.project` files.

You have to check out your project and configure it for each IDE independently.

Maven would obviously make your life a lot easier since this can auto configure your project.

Comment: +1 Some people say you should version your `.settings` folder... but they are idiots :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is my first attempt with Eclipse + SVN creating a project from scratch. I'm learning as we go and I'd like you to take a look at the updated question if you can see now what if left to configure my build and versioning environment. It seems my Java 7 is missing a JRE and I don't know how to add one. Can you tell me more how to proceed? I will also definitely consider Maven for this project since I can decide about that this time.

Comment: I only use eclipse and not rad but you have to add your JRE under the preference `Installed JREs`, not `Execution environments`.